# Pass object key name argument into function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which takes a dataset, field name and search string then uses ES2015's arrow functions to find the result.

Example call is:

```
var whatever = myDataSet.find(entry => entry.name === 'John');
```

I need to build this from arguments within a function but I cannot get the field name in.

The function:

```
findSingle: function(dataSet, fieldName, searchString){
    return dataSet.find(entry => entry.fieldName === searchString);
}
```

Which I'd call with:

```
my.nameSpace.findSingle(dataSetName, 'name', 'John');
```

And I expect it to then call:

```
dataSetName.find(entry => entry.name=== 'john');
```

But it fails. (If I hard code `entry.name` it work as expected) I'm pretty sure it's because I'm passing a string to be an object property for `entry.name` but I can't think of another way to do this.

Is it possible to pass strings into object properties like this or should I do it a different way?

Comment: `entry[fieldName]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
findSingle: function(dataSet, fieldName, searchString){
    return dataSet.find(entry => entry[fieldName] === searchString);
}
```

To be able to use a variable to fetch an object property, you have to use the bracket notation (object[key]). Dot notation (object.key) is interpreted literally and looks for a key named "key".

In your case entry.fieldName equals entry['fieldName']. To use the variable called fieldName, you have to do entry[fieldName].

Comment: Damn it, tried everything but this - thanks! Will accept when I can